# how to get freebase entity fact level attributions information?

Tags: freebase

I am trying to find out the source for attribute level information. I see the website http://www.freebase.com has attribution and creator information but unfortunately this is missing from the freebase dump. Is there a way to find out, what all attributes per entity has been added to freebase e.g. 150,0000 person names are from wikipedia and 300000 songs' artist names are from musicbrainz. I see MQL query also provide this information but there seems to size limit.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I had tried using dumps, apis and mql queries. Is there a way to get all entities from single source ? that will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This information isn't available in the dumps.  The API (ie MQL) is the only way to get it.  You can use the MQL cursor functionality to page through large result sets, but the API isn't really designed to be used to fetch hundreds of thousands of items.